# How tableFooterView works?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to animate `UITableView` data reloading and I do so:

```
let animation: () -> () = { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView?.reloadData()
}

UIView.transitionWithView(tableView,
                          duration: 0.35,
                          options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: animation,
                          completion: nil)
```

Unfortunately, `tableFooterView` isn't animate with it.

[image: Example]

I've tried different properties like `frame`, `contentInset`, `contentSize` etc. Finally, I've got working solution but it's weird and I can't find anything about `tableFooterView` working logic. Code:

```
let animation: () -> () = { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView?.reloadData()
    self?.tableView?.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 1)
}
```

Moreover, it works with different `y` value except zero and I can't understand why.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: try calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded right after your self?.tableView?.reloadData() as you appeared to be animating only content change, calling layoutIfNeeded in your animation block will animate the layout change if there is any.

Comment: @ldindu, thanks for response. `layoutIfNeeded` didn't help, result is like on first gif